# large website, many users, how to identify users uniquely

Tags: php, database-design, social-networking

Most websites require that the username be unique. I'm noticing that SO allows duplicate usernames, which could be good when you have a very large website like SO (which I'm guessing they do to avoid usernames like chris123, chris213, chris321 which start to look confusing themselves). But is allowing duplicate usernames generally a relatively poor implementation? It can be confusing to get 2 answers from 2 users that have the same username.

So what other alternatives are there for large sites that have a large number of users that need to interact with each other? I'm thinking something that's not even username-based, but not sure what.

Comment: I personally think that not-unique visible name for sites of any size is a bad practice.

Comment: Little confused with your question! What other options means... ?

Comment: @Shoban I mean one option is to require the unique usernames and you end up with chris123 and chris132 and chris321 and so on. Another option is just allow duplicates chris and chris and chris. Both options in my opinion start to get hairy for large number of users. Are there other options that people use for this sort of identification on large websites, maybe something that's not even username-based at all or a combination of username and something else. Not even sure I know what. Maybe someone ran into a good alternative already.

Answer (score 2):

While having distinct usernames (typically used for login) is a near absolute requirement, there is no reason that the display alias has any requirement to be unique so far as there are discernable methods to identify the actual user for other individuals using the system. This is a fairly common practice among discussion forums since really there are many "Jeff Smith"'s out there. SO for example, uses the reputation of a user and links back to their profile as mechanisms in differentiating the actual users involved. The logins themselves though, must have a form of uniqueness to them.

As an addenum to clarify my comment:

The sky (and your imagination) really are the limit on how to uniquely identify an alias. Outside of the standard profile link you could add on other unique characteristics (should you want the alias to be relatively unmistakable). As an example of some I havne't seen: use unique fonts or colors when renering the alias ... the blue sanscript Jeff Smith is different than the yellow arial Jeff Smith (just an example method)

Comment: +1 but The need for uniqueness to login is understood, and the benefit of uniqueness for identification is the point I was making in the question, so the question is: what other alternatives do I have to identify users uniquely other than chris123, chris321, chris231? which doesn't look very good

Comment: Let users identify themselves, but add on other unique sets of data (unique/random avatars, reputation points, links to profiles, /. style userIds) are among the most common.

Comment: I amended my answer to provide an example ... was beyond the 5 min to go in this comment and I believe it is better reflected there. For downvoters, please provide comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this in the past with my own website, and I find the best way is to identify a user is by their email address.

This is a very simple method, because it allows multiple usernames (or names, just like Facebook), and you can always identify uniqueness by their User ID in the database, and to show that on the website, maybe even show their username, avatar and possibly their location.

example:

```
chris123 (AZ) - chris123@example.com
chris123 (WA) - chris123.west@example.com
chris321 (AZ) - chris321@example.com
```

Comment: +1 but I doubt email is a good idea, because I can take chris123 and add gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc. and spam.

Comment: There really is no fool proof way of preventing that, just like on every other site. I could create multiple instances of myself and spam on any website, including SO (but I won't). The only way to slow down the amount of spam would be to use an SMS activation service, allowing only ONE email and Phone number to be connected. Back on topic, look at XBOX live, they have unique gamer tags. Maybe it's best just to stick with something that's tried and true, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two distinct issues; authorisation and personalisation.

Most sites will stick with using emails for uniquely authorising someone as these are already guaranteed to be unique. SO uses open authentication which means I haven't specified a 'username' for authentication with them in a long time. My [OpenID](http://openid.net) has my email and my password and handles the authorisation part for SO.

The other part is personalisation which should most certainly allow users to choose duplicate names if they so desire. This needs to be tied to the authenticating details and would normally be done using a separate unique number generated specifically by the site. This then links the username for authorisation and the username to display. I would guess that this also forms part of the primary key in whatever database structure users are stored in.

If you check the links for each profile name you will see a number in the url and this is what uniquely identifies you on the site and ties `twitter` to your email/username for login by the number `629665`. Your user page link is https://stackoverflow.com/users/629665/twitter

Whilst I can clearly see your chosen display name and your unique id on the site I don't know your authorising identity which you get to keep private and helps to keep you secure.

Answer (score 0):

--> Choosing username, isnt something great idea.
--> may be u can go for email id and username.

```
--> best is to Generate a unique ID for every user bro.
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, your question is quite ambiguous, I've edited the title to make it more clear.

There is no question how to *identify* a user. If you look at stackoverflow user linfo link, you'll notice old good autoincremented unique number. No problem with it.

Thus, I suppose your question is how one user can recognize another. I think it's not that big deal as collisions very rare and one can always tell by user reputation and that ID.